# What is the easiest way to select all Geofence locations for push messages

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, mobilepush, geolocation, push

Lets say we have over 500+ locations and we want to set up a push message for all of them.
What is the easiest way to select all the locations to prevent us from having to click each of the 500+ store locations.

Api? If so what is the correct syntax for referencing the locations?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to first GET all your locations from the [/push/v1/location REST route](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/getLocations.htm). And then, either update your existing message using [PUT /push/v1/message/{messageId}](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/updatePushMessage.htm) and passing in your array of Location IDs returned in your GET to the geofences property of your PUT request or create a new message from scratch using [POST /push/v1/message](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/createPushMessage.htm).

Comment: I was going to recommend this more simply with: use the API, but yeah, what @Macca said :)

Comment: I have not implemented this yet but it sounds like it would work!